# Как сделать кортеж кортежей и прогнать его сабсетом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, tuple

```
    def test_urls_uses_correct_template_guest_user(self): 
        templates_url_names = { 
            '/': 'posts/index.html', 
            f'/group/{self.post.group.slug}/': 'posts/group_list.html', 
            f'/profile/{self.post.author}/': 'posts/profile.html', 
            f'/posts/{self.post.id}/': 'posts/post_detail.html', 
            '/create/': 'posts/create_post.html', 
        } 
        for address, template in templates_url_names.items(): 
            with self.subTest(address=address): 
                response = self.authorized_client.get(address) 
                self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как переделать в кортеж кортежей,
проверять будем не хардкод урлы, а реверс на имя с аргументом.
Нужно учесть что реверс нужен только в месте вызова.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо словаря просто пишете кортеж кортежей:

```
        templates_url_names = ( 
            ('/', 'posts/index.html'),
            ...
        )
```

А при переборе сущностей просто убирате `.items()` и всё.

Что такое реверс в данном контексте я не понял.